# How to say: 'to you, too' or 'you as well'

Tags: meaning, vocabulary, formality, salutation, informal

Example:
Person A: 'Have a nice weekend!'
Person B: 'You too!'

Answer (score 10):

I usually respond to:

*"Schönes Wochenende!"*

with

*"Gleichfalls!"*

or

"*Ihnen/Dir auch!"*

or, less formal:

*"Auch so!"*

Of course, to be polite, you could start the response with a *"Danke!"*.

Comment: "Du mich auch" darf man nur unter guten Freunden verwenden. Es stammt aus einem alten Sketch und wird als Antwort auf "kannst mich mal am A... lecken" verstanden.

Comment: @Robert: LOL! Gib nebasjoa keine falschen Ideen, sonst sagt er das vielleicht noch. <g>

Comment: "Ebenso" is also possible and increasingly, regrettably one also hears "Für Sie/Dich auch!"

Answer (score 0):

In German you Add First an **Danke** (Thanks) so you say **"Danke, du auch!"**
And when you dont want to Add **Danke** just say **"Du auch"** or **"Dir auch"** what means "The same to you"

Comment: I agree it is common to add "Danke" but you have to take care of the formal choice Du/Ihnen. It is very important to point out the difference otherwise it is offending.

Comment: That's A pretty aLeatoric use of caPital LettErs in youR ANswer.

Comment: @user29249 I think you have make the use of case explicit, i.e. in response to "Schönes Wochenende" only "Dir auch" is correct, while to "Hab' ein schönes Wochenende" only allows for "Du auch".